# How to render multiple hook states into my JSX?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a useEffect function to communicate with my Api. Then I converted the string "were numbers in  form of strings" to integer numbers, after this I made if statements to create ratings from these numbers. This part worked like a charm, then I created a hook to change its value based on the If/Else statement. Till now everything is fine on the console.log. But when I try to render into my JSX appears just one rating.
This is my code:

```
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState([]);
    const [score, setScore] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
       api.get('measures').then(res => {
        // this.setState({measures: res.data.measures})
        this.state.measures = res.data.measures
        this.state.measures.map(x => {
            let duration = parseInt(x.duration);
            console.log(duration)
            if (duration < 5 && duration === 5) {
                setScore("10")
                console.log("Average were 10")
            } else if (duration > 5 && duration < 10) {
                setScore("7")
                console.log("Average were 7")
            } else if (duration >= 10 && duration < 15) {
                setScore("5")
                console.log("Average were 5")
            } else if (duration >= 15 && duration <= 20) {
                setScore("3")
                console.log("Average were 3")
                // setScore('33')
            } else if (duration > 20) {
                setScore("1")
                console.log("Average were 1")
                // setScore('1')
            }else {
                console.log("Err")
            }
        });
    });
}, []);
```

On my console.log I get the results that I want to show in the JSX:

```
LOG      15
LOG      Average were 3
LOG      12
LOG      Average were 5
LOG      50
LOG      Average were 1
LOG      17
LOG      Average were 3
```

But on my JSX appear:[image: AchtungAnahlt]

My JSX is:

```
                                <View style={styles.leftBlock}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500', marginBottom: 5}}>Profile</Text>
                                <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>Average Score: {score} </Text>
                            </View>
```

Comment: there's a couple of interesting things going on, first your useEffect will only run once since you're not passing anything for it to compare in the dependencies array. Second, you use the keyword `this` in a functional component (big no no), store it in the state. Also extract that if else logic to a separate utility function and then pass the result to a variable and setState with it.

Comment: if you still have questions I can make a more elaborate response.

Comment: Changing from "this.state.measures = res.data.measures" you mean setDuration(res.data.measures)? Can I extract to a variable without using a hook?

Comment: @GabrielSavian  I can't understand what are you trying to do in this line `if (duration < 5 && duration === 5)`. if you need to compare duration is less than or equal to 5 then use `if (duration <= 5)`

Comment: I'm trying to pick up the values from the api and set up a score manually. And I want to show this manually score just like in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering is happening after the `useEffect` executed. Because of that In your code setScore set the score value to the last value of `res.data.measures`. Instead of mapping values in `useEffect` you can save `res.data.measures` in a measures state. Then map that measures state on rendering.

```js
const YourView = () => {

  const [duration, setDuration] = useState([]);
  const [measures, setMeaures] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    api.get('measures').then(res => {
      setMeasures(res.data.measures);
    });
  }, []);

  return ( < div > {
      measures.map(x => {
          let duration = parseInt(x.duration);
          let score = 0;
          console.log(duration);
          if (duration < 5 && duration === 5) {
            score = 10;
            console.log("Average were 10")
          } else if (duration > 5 && duration < 10) {
            score = 7;
            console.log("Average were 7")
          } else if (duration >= 10 && duration < 15) {
            score = 5;
            console.log("Average were 5")
          } else if (duration >= 15 && duration <= 20) {
            score = 3;
            console.log("Average were 3")
            // setScore('33')
          } else if (duration > 20) {
            score = 1;
            console.log("Average were 1")
            // setScore('1')
          } else {
            console.log("Err")
          }
          return ( < View style = {
              styles.leftBlock
            } >
            <
            Text style = {
              {
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: '500',
                marginBottom: 5
              }
            } > Profile < /Text> <Text style = { {
              fontSize: 15
            }
          } > Average Score: {
            score
          } < /Text> </View > )
      });
  } < /div>);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```